# How can I install Brother printer hl-l2321d in Ubuntu14.04?

Tags: 14.04, printing, brother

I tried to install Brother printer HL-L2321D for my Acer laptop running Ubuntu 14.04, but in vain.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Brother supply a Driver Install Tool; get it from here [Brother - Driver Install Tool](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=as_ot&lang=en&prod=hll2321d_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625&dlang=true) and click to SAVE it and it should end up in your Downloads folder; open a terminal; copy the commands below; and paste each one; line by line into a terminal; hit the ENTER key after each paste; please for help if you need it with any of the above instructions

```
cd Downloads
gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.1 (1).1-1.gz
sudo bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.1 (1).1-1 HL-L2321D
```

the final command activates the install tool; watch the terminal as it runs, as it may ask you questions; let us know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

First, download `linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1.gz` using the following link:

https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=as_ot&lang=en&prod=hll2321d_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625&dlang=true

- `cd Downloads`.
- extract using `-gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1.gz`.
- use the `sudo su` command.
- password is password.
- `sudo bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1 HL-L2321D`

Note - local internet connectivity is compulsory for installing these packages.